# Range-based loop for std::queue

Tags: c++, c++11, queue

I'm trying to look for a substitute in `std::vector` in my project, and I found out that `std::queue` is what I'm looking for.

I have lots of function that uses `range-based loop` for iteration and I'm trying to maintain it as far as I can.

I try to compile a `range-based loop` in `std::queue` but all I get are compile errors

> error: no matching function for call to 'begin(std::queue&)'

Doesn't `std::queue` support range base loop?

I did try `Google search` but didn't find any topic regarding to this.

**Update:**

My compiler is `GCC v4.7.1`

`-std=c++11` is enabled

And here's the faulty test code:

```
std::queue<int> Q;

for (int i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
    Q.push(i);

std::cout << "\nqueue contains: ";
for (auto i : Q)
    std::cout << i << ", ";
```

Comment: For future questions, you can try forming your test case on an online compilation environment such as [http://ideone.com](http://ideone.com) which will immediately let you know if you have a compiler issue or not. Here, http://ideone.com/kIln7G  it gives the same error you mentioned

Comment: @mr5 Ok, both gcc 4.8.1 and clang++ 3.4 fail with your example.

Comment: @Morwenn Then is that an invalid code?

Comment: @mr5 Actually, `std::queue` doesn't have a method `begin()`. When I told you it worked, I confused `std::queue` for a `std::deque`. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the answer is actually pretty simple: there is no function `begin()` in `std::queue` and there isn't any overload of `std::begin` taking a `std::queue` either. You can have a look at the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue).

The core problem is that `std::queue` is not meant to be iterated over. It exists to satisfy other needs. If you really need to iterate over it, you should just use the underlying container (by default `std::deque`) which supports iteration and for which your code would be valid.

Comment: I'm still waiting for other answers but I think there's no more different answer than this. I'll look for `std::deque` if it fits my need. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Note that `std::queue` is only an adaptor class which "adds" the two functions `push` and `pop` with a proper meaning. You could always also use the underlying `std::deque` but then you don't have these convenience functions. But you can also declare a `std::deque` *and* a `std::queue`; use the `deque` for iterating and `queue` for pushing and popping conveniently.

Comment: Strictly speaking it doesn't "add" the two functions, it replaces the entire container interface with those two functions. The purpose of `std::queue` pretty much is to prevent the user accessing the underlying container other than in FIFO order. Formally the purpose is to implement a simple Abstract Data Type, but it amounts to interface narrowing. That is to say, the reason `queue` exists is to prevent the user iterating over it. If you want to use a `deque` as a FIFO in addition to other uses you can, it's just the functions are named `push_back` and `pop_front`.

Answer (score 2):

Although `std::queue` doesn't support iteration, it does have a **copy constructor** which allows us to transfer the contents of a temporary copy of the queue to another temporary container that would support iteration (e.g. `std::vector`, `std::list`, or if using C++11, `std::forward_list`).

So, while it does cost some runtime overhead and isn't quite as nice as being able to iterate over the structure directly if the goal is to have a reasonably convenient way to iterate over the values of a `std::queue` variable, you might consider using a templated function like the following (adding it to an appropriate header file):

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <list>

// returns an iterable copy of the given queue
template<class T> std::list<T> toList(std::queue<T> qCopy) {
    std::list<T> returnList;
    while (!qCopy.empty()) {
        returnList.push_back(qCopy.front());
        qCopy.pop();
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Incorporating into OP's use case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::queue<int> Q;

    for (int i = 0;i < 10; ++i)
        Q.push(i);

    std::cout << "\nqueue contains: ";
    for (auto i : toList(Q))
        std::cout << i << ", ";

    return 0;
}
```